# Parsing file for relevant fields

Tags: regex, bash, perl, pattern-matching, match

How can a regular expression be used on a file with:

```
A7247, partOf:["LTA_SO", "dontact"]
alat, partOf:["WTP_ZR"]
yello, partOf:[]
```

And get back (notice not being a part of anything):

```
A7247:LTA_SO,dontact
alat:WTP_ZR
yello:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yea, I can get the first field (A7247 and alat) with the following: ^[^,]*

Comment: Trying to find quotes (") now and find values between them. Do you think that is the right strategy?

Comment: Found a way to get everything in between brackets too: "(?:[^\\]|\\.)*"

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side (the part after the `:`) looks like JSON. If that's true, it would be better to treat it as such:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($lhs, $rhs) = split(/:/, $_, 2);
    my $array_ref = decode_json($rhs);

    $lhs = (split(/,/, $lhs))[0];
    $rhs = join(',', @$array_ref);

    print join(':', $lhs, $rhs), "\n";
}

__DATA__
A7247, partOf:["LTA_SO", "dontact"]
alat, partOf:["WTP_ZR"]
yello, partOf:[]
```

Output:

```
A7247:LTA_SO,dontact
alat:WTP_ZR
yello:
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! That worked really well and is broken up enough that I understand it well.

Comment: @telecomToperl Is it actually JSON?